# Issues in dropdown css

Tags: css, reactjs, multi-select

I am using this library [react-multi-select-component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TmSW.png) for multiSelect dropdown.
This is my code :

```
      const [selected,setSelected] = useState([]);
      const options = ["2022-02-01","2022-02-10"];
      <MultiSelect
          className="prefill__Dropdown"
          options={options}
          value={selected}
          onChange={setSelected}
          labelledBy="select"
          valueRenderer={customValueRender}
          overrideStrings={{
            selectSomeItems: "Prefill Past Observation",
            allItemsAreSelected: "All Items are Selected",
            selectAll: "Select All Past Observations",
            search: "Search",
            noOptions: "No Past Observations Available"
          }}
          style={{cursor:"pointer"}}
       />
```

where , **options** is an array and **selected** is a state of type array . setState is the method to change the state "selected".

When no options are selected the image looks like this :

[image: When no options are selected]

The issue , I am facing is :
When any option is selected . The width of the options get reduced . The below image shows the issue .

[image: When option is selected]

How do I fix the **width issue** of the **option** when any of the options are **selected** ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a CSS issue, you can inspect in your browser the selected element and override the CSS under prefill__Dropdown class.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how styling can we overridden in material-ui and then fix your issue.
[Material-ui](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/).

There is a clean method overriding things inside material ui rather than inspecting and then styling it.

Answer (score 0):

Material ui has very well documentation regarding overriding css through `sx` property check it out [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/)